# Cannot produce coverage in TeamCity using NUnit and PartCover

Tags: nunit, partcover, teamcity-8.0

I'm using TeamCity version 8.0.4.

I've got a build step that uses the NUnit runner and PartCover as the coverage tool.

I've followed the steps outlined here (http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/23/using-teamcity-with-partcover-4/).  That is, I've copied the PartCover.dll and appropriately renamed it and used the XSLT linked in the blog.

The "Include Assemblies" field only has:

```
[*]*
```

The "Exclude Assemblies" field only has:

```
[*.Tests]*
```

My build log gets the following message after correctly executing the tests:

```
No executable code was detected. 
The issue could be caused by one of the following:
- Include / exclude patterns are incorrect
- Assemblies are compiled without debugging information
- .pdb files are not available
- Visual Studio code coverage is enabled for MSTest
- .testrunconfig is used for MSTest and Visual Studio code coverage is not disabled (CodeCoverage section with enable="true" is present)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I un-installed PartCover and re-installed it and now it seems to be working.  I think the issue was that I was using a beta version of PartCover instead of the stable release.

Comment: PartCover only handles 32 bit, if you require 64 bit support then you may want to look into [OpenCover](http://scubamunki.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/adding-opencover-to-teamcity.html).